# Исключение при вывове конструктора Page через рефлексию

Tags: c#

```
public class InstallerStep
{
    ...

    /// <summary>
    /// Класс страницы GUI
    /// </summary>
    public Type PageClass { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Страница
    /// </summary>
    public Page Page { get; set; }

    ...
}

private void CreateNewPageForCurrentStep()
    {
        ConstructorInfo constructorInfo = CurrentUserStep.PageClass.GetConstructor(new Type[] { });
        CurrentUserStep.Page = (Page)constructorInfo.Invoke(new object[] { });
    }
```

а строке

```
CurrentUserStep.Page = (Page)constructorInfo.Invoke(new object[] { });
```

создаётся исключение:

```
11.04.2016 10:28:27.983 Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeConstructor(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object[] args, SignatureStruct& signature, RuntimeType declaringType)
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeConstructor(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object[] args, SignatureStruct signature, RuntimeType declaringType)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke(Object[] parameters)
at Installer.InstallerWizardData.InstallerData.CreateNewPageForCurrentStep() in C:\Задачи\KS-5600.Скрипты\cs-installer\Installer\Installer\InstallerWizardData\InstallerData.cs:line 117
at Installer.InstallerWizardData.InstallerData.NextPage() in C:\Задачи\KS-5600.Скрипты\cs-installer\Installer\Installer\InstallerWizardData\InstallerData.cs:line 95
at Installer.SystemClasses.NavigationButtonsControl.NextButton_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in C:\Задачи\KS-5600.Скрипты\cs-installer\Installer\Installer\SystemClasses\NavigationButtonsControl.xaml.cs:line 64
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Installer.WAS.Configuration.ConfigurationPage..ctor() in C:\Задачи\KS-5600.Скрипты\cs-installer\Installer\Installer\WAS\Configuration\ConfigurationPage.xaml.cs:line 39
```

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: как выглядит класс `Page`?

Comment: приведите пример класс Page, у него имеется пустой конструктор?

Comment: и еще добавьте, что за `PageClass`

Comment: Покажите класс `ConfigurationPage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TargetInvocationException - это исключение-обертка.

Настоящее исключение возникло у вас внутри конструктора класса Page.

Comment: А точнее внутри `ConfigurationPage`: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Installer.WAS.Configuration.ConfigurationPage..ctor() in C:\Задачи\KS-5600.Скрипты\cs-installer\Installer\Installer\WAS\Configuration\ConfigurationPage.xaml.cs:line 39